# Keeping database consistency over a REST interface

Tags: database, mobile

I have a local database on a mobile database. Every few minutes, the device looks through its tables and sends through a REST interface to a server any data that is not marked as uploaded. Here is an example table:

```
id | name | phone | uploaded
1 | "bob" | "444" | 0
```

What gets sent through the REST interface is:

```
name : "bob", phone : "444"
```

and the server will respond with:

```
status : "OK"
```

Once this "OK" message is received by the mobile device, it will mark those records as `uploaded=1`. This should work fine to keep the device consistent with what has actually happened. The problem is that the server might receive two of these messages from the mobile device (for whatever reason) and will insert two records with the exact same data into the server database.

What are some ways to stop this from occuring?

I thought of a uniqueness index over all of the fields in the server database, but I feel that there must be a better way.

Comment: Why do you sent two update messages when you only need one? That's the problem that you must address

Comment: Well any number of things can cause an accidental 'double-send': a faulty connection, accidentally pressing 'upload' twice before the server responds. Anyways, you can't just leave it to chance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle this problem server-side or client-side.

As you already noticed, you can avoid duplicate records on your server component just adding a UNIQUE constraint on your database table, maybe to your ID column. With that, every-time you try to store a duplicate message on the DBMS the database will complain.

On the client side, you just need to add a STATE column on your mobile database table: This column should only support three values: UPLOAD_PENDING, UPLOAD_IN_TRANSIT and UPLOAD_FINISHED. This column is meant to replace you UPLOADED field, and should be updated when the tuple is created (UPLOAD_PENDING), you already started an upload (UPLOAD_IN_TRANSIT) and the upload is done (UPLOAD_FINISHED). You should check the state field value before staring a new upload to avoid your duplicate message problem.

You can choose any of this approaches, but I strongly suggest you to use both.

Comment: I ended up sending up the local db's id along with the rest of the info, and created a unique constraint on the 'local_id' field in the server db.